# Sql consult with many WHERE LIKE fields

Tags: php, mysqli, where-clause, sql-like

I'm programming a searcher, this searcher works with the condition of a city code (or id_city), that means that the results must be only from the selected city code or codes. So, i pass the value 1 for cities id_city=1 and id_city=2 , and the value 2 for cities id_city=3 and id_city=4.

```
if ($city==1){
$setzone = "citycode in ('1','2')"; }
elseif($city==2){
$setzone = "citycode in ('3','4')";}
```

The variable $setzone, have numbers that I use in the sql where "citycode" is a field on my table.

So, in the front end, the user can search between diferent "fields" to get a result like name, ocassion,zone, kindfood.

In my consult i have something like this:

```
$restaurants=$mysqli->query("select id, name,zone, ocassion, citycode, 
                                    kf.kindfood as food from restaurants as r
                                    inner join kind_food as kf on r.foodcode=kf.id_food
                                    where ".$setzone."
                                     and name like '%".$mysqli->real_escape_string($search)."%'
                                     or zone like '%".$mysqli->real_escape_string($search)."%'
                                     or ocassion like '%".$mysqli->real_escape_string($seach)."%'
                                     or kindfood like '%".$mysqli->real_escape_string($search)."%'
                                     order by id desc");
```

The problem is that this consult can only search the names in the $setzone, but if I search something else like kindfood, ocassion, zone gets all the result and ignores the $setzone.

Comment: Brackets, brackets, brackets

Comment: Thank you. Now i can sleep. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parentheses are your friend:

```
$restaurants=$mysqli->query("select id, name,zone, ocassion, citycode, 
                             kf.kindfood as food from restaurants as r
                             inner join kind_food as kf on r.foodcode=kf.id_food
                             where ".$setzone."
here -->                     and (name like '%".$mysqli->real_escape_string($search)."%'
                             or zone like '%".$mysqli->real_escape_string($search)."%'
                             or ocassion like '%".$mysqli->real_escape_string($seach)."%'
                             or kindfood like '%".$mysqli->real_escape_string($search)."%'
and here -->                 ) order by id desc");
```

Without these 2 parentheses, the `OR` filters always win. With, you cluster them together and still require the `$setzone`.

[Read up on the concept of 'operator precedence'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx).

Comment: I had the feeling that it was something simple. I really apreciate your help. Now i can sleep. Regards.